# trying to grab string from url

Tags: php, url, if-statement, strstr

I have a function to grab the current url - found here: http://webcheatsheet.com/php/get_current_page_url.php -  and I am trying to look for a string -  WordPress category slug - inside of it:

```
function curPageURL() {
     $pageURL = 'http';
     if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}
     $pageURL .= "://";
     if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
      $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
     } else {
      $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
     }
     return $pageURL;
    }
            //echo $pageURL;    
    if (strstr($pageURL, 'pro')) 
    { 
        echo "cool!";}
        else {echo "bummer";}`
```

The url $pageURL when echoed does have the full url with the pro as part of the url, but bummer is echoed anyways meaning either my if statement is of or that my `strstr` does not work. What is it?

Comment: use parse_url($url) in your php file to get proper fields from the URL, you can achieve the needed result.

Comment: Could you give us some example `$pageURL`s?

Comment: Reading `parse_url` @ http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php now. Not sure yet how I can use it to check for a specific string and use if else to execute code.

Comment: @ mathematical.coffee Sample: http://subdomain.domain.com/pro/tarifs/ or http://domain.com/pro/trees/

Comment: so are you actually calling `$pageURL=curPageURL()` anywhere in your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that portion of code is copied exactly from your code, then you are not setting the `$pageURL`. 
Before your condition you should call

```
$pageURL=curPageURL();
```

to make sure you are searching the word "pro" inside the actual url.

If you have code inbetween the condition and your function declaration, then take a look at the details regarding `strstr` and what evaluates to `FALSE`

`strstr` Returns the portion of string, or `FALSE` if needle is not found.

In PHP when converting to boolean, the following values are considered FALSE:

the boolean `FALSE` itself

the integer `0` (zero)

the float `0.0` (zero)

the empty string, and the string "`0`"

an array with zero elements

an object with zero member variables (PHP 4 only)

the special type `NULL` (including unset variables)

SimpleXML objects created from empty tags

Comment: I thought I was missing a connection between the function and the conditional! Thanks! I initially thought I had to make the variable in the function global, but that did not work. I guess making the function global would not have mattered either. I guess it was not a scope issue, but simply a variable declaration issue. FYI my statement answers "cool" or true now. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

**Use this it will help you**

```
$str = "first=value&arr[]=foo+bar&arr[]=baz";
parse_str($str);
echo $first;  // value
echo $arr[0]; // foo bar
echo $arr[1]; // baz
```